# Compare 2 cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I have 2 cv::Mat array (with same size), and when I want to compare them (if identical), I used cv::compare

```
cv::compare(mat1,mat2,dst,cv::CMP_EQ);
```

Is there any function that return true/false?

Comment: you get a whole Mat full of true / false ;)

Comment: I just want to get true/false as return value.

Comment: "I want to compare them" - that's probably the weak point of your question. are you looking for similarity ? pixel-wise identity ? same object shown in both images ? all of it would require different measures.

Comment: My mistake. I want to compare if they are identical.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need to compare 2 cv::Mat by sizes, then you might check

```
if(mat1.size() == mat2.size())
    //do stuff
else
    //do other stuff
```

If you need to check if 2 cv::Mat are equal, you can perform the <del>AND</del> **XOR** operator and check if the result is a cv::Mat full of zeros:

```
cv::bitwise_xor(mat1, mat2, dst);        
if(cv::countNonZero(dst) > 0) //check non-0 pixels
   //do stuff in case cv::Mat are not the same
else
  //do stuff in case they are equal
```

Comment: not sure which one is faster, but `dst = mat1-mat2;` followed by the countNonZero would do the same (result inverted).

Comment: the bit operators perform a little bit faster than the difference, that's why I proposed bitwose_and

Comment: See answer by J. Roy: bitwise_xor should be used rather than bitwise_and.

Comment: @sircolinton I've corrected that, thanks

Comment: @madduci Thanks, corrected my vote correspondingly :-)

Comment: dst = mat1-mat2 is returning a clamped value range, so any pixel of mat2 that is bigger than the according one in mat 1 is returning 0. So only dst = (mat1-mat2) + (mat2-mat1) will work, and now its obvious that the bitwise must be faster!

Comment: Would you say this is faster than `bool eq = cv::countNonZero(a!=b) == 0;` from the other question?

Answer (score 6):

> If you need to check if 2 cv::Mat are equal, you can perform the AND operator and check if the result is a cv::Mat full of zeros:

The AND operator is not the good one for this task. If a matrix is all 0, it will always return true regardless if the other matrix is all 0 or not.

The XOR must be used in this case.

Here the modified version of blackibiza code:

```
cv::bitwise_xor(mat1, mat2, dst);        
if(cv::countNonZero(dst) > 0) //check non-0 pixels
   //do stuff in case cv::Mat are not the same
else
  //do stuff in case they are equal
```

Answer (score 0):

This function returns true/false based on similarity (untested)

```
bool MyCompare(Mat img1, Mat img2)
{
    int threshold = (double)(img1.rows * img1.cols) * 0.7; 

    cv::compare(img1 , img2  , result , cv::CMP_EQ );
    int similarPixels  = countNonZero(result);

    if ( similarPixels  > threshold ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: here you compare them based on a threshold. If you want to understand if they are fully equal, you must compare the single bits or set threshold to zero